# Unit testing using karma jasmine for http data not resulting the correct result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have created the karma jasmine unit testing file for checking my json result. But I could not get the exact result which expected. Here is my service.

```
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'AidaApi' )
        .factory( 'AidaApiSrv', AidaApiSrv );

    AidaApiSrv.$inject = [ '$http', '$log' ];


    const apiUrl = 'https://test.com/';

    return {
        getSinglePromotion: getSinglePromotion,
    };

    function getSinglePromotion( recordId ) {

        return $http.get( apiUrl + recordId )
            .then( complete )
            .catch( failed );

        function complete( response ) {
            $log.info( 'Single AIDA promotion data loaded.' );
            return response.data
        }

        function failed( error ) {
            $log.error( 'Failed to fetch single promotion: ' + error.data );
        }
    }
 }
```

I have written the karma jasmine script for check this service function is

```
 describe( "aida-api-service", function () {

    var AidaApiSrv, $http, responseData, mockSponsors, fakedMainResponse;
    var mockPromotion = {
        id: 2,
        field_11: 70
    };

    beforeEach( function () {
        module( 'AidaApi' );
        inject( function ( _AidaApiSrv_, $httpBackend ) {
            $http = $httpBackend;
            AidaApiSrv = _AidaApiSrv_;
        } );
    } );
    it( 'check single promotion', function ( done ) {
        var testPromotion = function ( promotion ) {
            expect( promotion.id )
                .toBe( mockPromotion.id );
            expect( promotion.field_11 )
                .toBe( mockPromotion.field_11 );
        };

        var failTest = function ( error ) {
            expect( error )
                .toBeUndefined();
        };

        $http.expectGET( 'https://test.com/2' )
            .respond( 200, mockPromotion );

        AidaApiSrv.getSinglePromotion( mockPromotion.id )
            .then( testPromotion )
            .catch( failTest )
            .finally( done );

        $http.flush();
    } );
 } );
```

With the above script i'm not getting any error. I am do not thing getting expected result. If i print **"promotion.field_11"** its displaying the value given in the in the **mockPromotion** promotion object. Not the expected result. Any idea?

Comment: You already pass `mockPromotion` to be the expected result with `$http.expectGET('https://test.com/2').respond(200, mockPromotion);`. What result do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But if I print "mockPromotion.field_11" should get the value "69" as expected resukt. But i am getting "70" which is already declared by me.

Comment: I don't even see a minus sign, where does field_11 become 69?

Comment: "field_11" of the api data which is return by the service is 69. How can i get that?....either using "promotion.field_11" or "mockPromotion.field_11"

Comment: For the unit tests, you don't actually make any real calls to the API; you just use the httpBackend service to mock the API behavior. If you want to make real API calls, exclude the httpBackend service completely from your tests (not recommended for unit testing, as the thing you are actually testing is your angular service, not the real API).

Answer (score 0):

> With the above script i'm not getting any error. I am i do not thing getting expected result. If i print "promotion.field_11" its displaying the value given in the in the mockPromotion promotion object

And from comment in question:

> If I print "mockPromotion.field‌​_11" should get the value "69" as expected result. But i am getting "70" which is already declared by me.

---

Based on your code is expected behavior. You are [mocking the http backend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) and defining what should be returned based on the URL (*other discriminators are possible as well but in this case its based only on URL*). An `$httpBackend` instance will never actually make an external connection, instead you define the behavior based on expected inputs (like result based on a URL).

You have defined the result as variable `mockPromotion` which was defined at the top as `var mockPromotion = {id: 2, field_11: 70};` and mocked your http service where if url `https://test.com/2` is used then that is returned as the data. You then inject this `$httpBackend` service in your angular factory and test it, here you are testing your factory code with a `$httpBackend` that does not connect to the actual API (which is good). So when called the `$httpBackend` will return the object you specified.

Now if you want to actually call your real service this would be called an integration test as you are testing multiple layers or tiers that are connected. You can do this by not using `$httpBackend`, use the actual `$http` service as you would when your app is actually running. I will not get into when or why to use integration tests but will say this, **what you have now is a good unit test and you should keep it.** If you want an integration test you should create a new test that does only that and use `$http` and not `$httpBackend`.

---

#### Side note

I think its a type-o (mistake in copy paste to S.O.) but I am pretty sure you meant to pass in `response` to the `testPromotion` function like so.

```
var testPromotion = function (response) {
    var promotion = response.data; // the promotion should be the data variable if this method is the callback for the `then` function
    expect(promotion.id).toBe(mockPromotion.id);
    expect(promotion.field_11).toBe(mockPromotion.field_11);
};
```